# PHP CRON job, not output HTTP headers

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that is called via a cron job, with the results sent to my email address:

```
"php /path/to/cron.php"
```

I only echo errors, otherwise nothing is outputted by me.  This way I can get an error report when things go wrong.  The problem is, I receive an email with ever cron execution, that only has the HTTP headers in it:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
Content-type: text/html
```

This is obviously a pain, receiving multiple emails every few minutes.  All I'd like to see are emails for cron jobs where I've echo'd something.

I want to keep the email being generated by the cron job if possible (instead of sending the email in-script). And I don't want to run it via wget, because my host counts that against my bandwidth.

All my searching has only shown me how to set headers, not remove/suppress the default ones. Am I going about this wrong?  Has anybody else seen this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
php -q /path/to/cron.php
```

From here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#24970

Comment: I knew it had to be something incredibly easy, 'cause I already tried the hard stuff :)  Thanks Joel

Answer (score 0):

Using this full command it will work first in configuration file call the your php file will be executed

`php -c /home1/sam/public_html/php.ini /home1/sam/public_html/sam_RFID/Android/Email.php`

Just Check It.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cPanel, just put the syntax as following:

```
php /home/<User>/public_html/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Your solution negates all output. Not what OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful note for others researching a very similar issue: Additionally, it should be noted that any trailing newlines or whitespace after a closing php tag will cause a cron job to produce seemingly blank output, even if headers are silenced.

`?>`

Many people choose to omit their php closing tag for this reason.